# ping failed without entry in main routing table

Tags: routes, ping

Ping failed if i delete the route entry in main table.

Here is the network situation:

```
[root@localhost ~]# ip a s dev eth1                                            
3: eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast qlen 1000 
    link/ether 00:1e:67:64:ee:b8 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff                         
    inet 192.168.19.22/24 brd 192.168.19.255 scope global eth1                 
    inet6 fe80::21e:67ff:fe64:eeb8/64 scope link                               
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever 

[root@localhost ~]# ip ro s
default via 192.168.19.254 dev eth1     

[root@localhost ~]# ip ru s
0:      from all lookup 255
32764:  from all to 192.168.19.22 lookup HOST
32765:  from 192.168.19.22 lookup HOST
32766:  from all lookup main
32767:  from all lookup default

[root@localhost ~]# ip ro s t HOST
192.168.19.0/24 dev eth1  scope link  src 192.168.19.22
default via 192.168.19.254 dev eth1

[root@localhost ~]# ping 192.168.19.51 -w 5
PING 192.168.19.51 (192.168.19.51) 56(84) bytes of data.

--- 192.168.19.51 ping statistics ---
6 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 4999ms

[root@localhost ~]# ping 192.168.19.51 -I eth1 -w 5                              
PING 192.168.19.51 (192.168.19.51) from 192.168.19.22 eth1: 56(84) bytes of data.

--- 192.168.19.51 ping statistics ---                                            
6 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 4999ms
```

But if I use `ping -I address` or `ping -I interface -r` the result is different.

```
[root@localhost ~]# ping 192.168.19.51 -I eth1 -w 5 -r -c 

3                      
    PING 192.168.19.51 (192.168.19.51) from 192.168.19.22 eth1: 56(84) bytes of data.
    64 bytes from 192.168.19.51: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=2.20 ms                      
    64 bytes from 192.168.19.51: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.226 ms                     
    64 bytes from 192.168.19.51: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.437 ms                     

    --- 192.168.19.51 ping statistics ---                                            
    3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2001ms                   
    rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.226/0.955/2.204/0.887 ms                                
    [root@localhost ~]# ping 192.168.19.51 -I 192.168.19.22 -w 5 -c 3            
PING 192.168.19.51 (192.168.19.51) from 192.168.19.22 : 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.19.51: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=1.86 ms                  
64 bytes from 192.168.19.51: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.630 ms                 
64 bytes from 192.168.19.51: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.210 ms                 

--- 192.168.19.51 ping statistics ---                                        
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2002ms               
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.210/0.902/1.866/0.702 ms
```

I know the difference between "-I" and "-r":

-I eth1 will revoke setsockopt with opt SO_BINDTODEVICE;

-I 192.168.19.22 will revoke bind;

-r will revoke setsockopt with opt SO_DONTROUTE;

If a add route entry in main table, it'll pass:

```
[root@localhost ~]# ip ro a 192.168.19.0/24 dev eth1          
[root@localhost ~]# ip ro s                                   
192.168.19.0/24 dev eth1  scope link                          
default via 192.168.19.254 dev eth1                           
[root@localhost ~]# ping 192.168.19.51 -c 3                   
PING 192.168.19.51 (192.168.19.51) 56(84) bytes of data.      
64 bytes from 192.168.19.51: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=1.99 ms   
64 bytes from 192.168.19.51: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.207 ms  
64 bytes from 192.168.19.51: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.435 ms  

--- 192.168.19.51 ping statistics ---                         
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2000ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.207/0.879/1.997/0.796 ms
```

If main table had a entry or ping with -I address or ping with -I interface -r, it'll pass.
But if ping with -I interface it'll not.

Why is that? What's the difference?